# Trying to use KDBG, but it produces error 11

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debugging

I am trying to start kdbg on Ubuntu, but it produces this error message:

```
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
```

What is going on?

Answer (score -1):

This problem is caused due to the pulse.mng file present in the location

```
/usr/share/kde4/apps/kdbg/icons/hicolor/22x22
```

delete the file and it will work.